# Admin rights prompt popup in C# application

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-3.0, uac

I have a function in my application which requires admin rights.

What I want is when I click the button to execute that function, it should ask for admin username and password. (Launch UAC dialog. Also show icon on that button.)

Is it possible?

[image]

PS: I know about launching the application with admin right by making modifications in manifest file.

Also this function is a part of a large program and it cannot be transferred to a separate program.

Comment: You have to restart your application once full admin access has been granted in order for you application to be able to take advantage of the new rights. Hence why @Rob has suggested that you use a seperate app. The best recommendation I can give is that you request full access rights when your application launches initially, if you really need it.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but our application can be even executed by Guest users (which is a requirement) and only sometimes we need admin rights.

Comment: @Raj I'm sure UAC doesn't work like that.  Good luck :)

Comment: How does Window 7/ Vista display a button which upon clicking pops UAC dialog?

Comment: @Raj, if you observe Task Manager (for example), look at the PID (Process Id) that it (`TaskMgr.exe`) has when you first load it, as opposed to its PID when you click the "Show processes from all users" button. Note that it changes. This is because it's re-launched with the appropriate privileges.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the icon using StockIcons.Shield from the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)

You can run a program with admin privileges without changing the program manifest using the "runas" verb (you can also use this to re-launch your program with admin rights):

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
   {
        Verb = "runas",
        FileName = "Notepad.exe",
   });
```

There is a COM API that let you create a COM object with admin rights inside a non-admin process, but I believe it's very difficult to use this from a .net application.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to achieve this is to have a secondary executable that contains the code that requires administrative rights, which is manifested appropriately. When your application needs to execute the code that requires administrative rights, call that program.

*For example:*

MyProgram.exe - no manifest
MyProgramElevated.exe - has a manifest that indicates it requires admin rights

When `MyProgram.exe` needs to perform an action as elevated it executes `MyProgramElevated.exe`, passing command line parameters indicating what elevated task is required.

Comment: That was the first thing i wanted to do but this function is a part of a large program and it cannot be transferred to a separate program.

Comment: @Raj, I'm not aware of any way to obtain the "full" token other than doing as I've suggested. I've added a few more tags to your question to hopefully make it more visible as someone else may know a solution I don't =)